# Rake exception management

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

Consider this Rake task:

```
namespace :foo do
  task :bar do
    begin
      raise 'foo'
    rescue RuntimeError => ex
      raise ex.class, 'bar', ex.backtrace
    end
  end
end
```

It results in the following output:

```
rake aborted!
bar
/home/vagrant/proj/lib/tasks/foo.rake:52:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
foo
/home/vagrant/proj/lib/tasks/foo.rake:52:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => foo:bar
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

As you can see, there's both the *original* exception (`foo`) as well as the new one (`bar`).
Why is that? I'd have expected the `foo` exception, that has been properly rescued, to not show up here.

Answer (score 0):

There's not both the original exception (`foo`).

Rakefile:

```
namespace :foo do
  task :bar do
    begin
      raise "message from foo"
    rescue RuntimeError => ex
      puts "#{ex.message}. foo is rescued"             # <= 1st
      raise ex.class, 'message from bar', ex.backtrace # <= 2nd
    end
  end
end
```

Output:

```
message from foo. foo is rescued # <= 1st
rake aborted!
message from bar # <= 2nd
/home/vagrant/Rakefile:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
message from foo # <= from backtrace
/home/vagrant/Rakefile:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => foo:bar
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @yhirano55. However, I'm afraid I still don't understand why the first exception's message would be in the backtrace at all? As far as I know, that's not standard Ruby behaviour?